# Twig: Replace placeholder in string with include

Tags: twig, twig.js

My question is similar to this one: [Twig: replace arbitrary token in variable with template include](http://Twig:%20replace%20arbitrary%20token%20in%20variable%20with%20template%20include).
I'm hoping things have change since it was asked.

I'm working with **twig.js**.

I have a server whose task is to listen to requests, receive datas, compile a twig file using those datas and send back the html.
The datas it's receiving is an object containing *texts, colors,* etc... that are passed as a context to the twig file.

In the data, users can send placeholders like `{foo}` and I'd like to replace those placeholders with `{% include 'partial.twig' %}`.

My first try was to use the filter `|replace` but it doesn't get processed:

```
{% set foo = foo|replace({'{foo}': '{% include "partial.twig" %}'}) %}
```

[See twigfiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/n285ga).

Is there any possibility to extend twig.js to be able to do something like that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do it in two steps, first capture the partial in a variable, then use the variable to replace the placeholder, e.g.

```html
{%- set bar -%}
    {% include "partial.twig" %}
{%- endset -%}

{% set foo = 'this is {foo}' %}

{% set foo = foo|replace({'{foo}': bar }) %}
{{ foo }}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/8rnecv)

*note:* `{%- ... -%}` *is used to strip whitespaces*

Comment: And here I am, wondering why I've spent so many hours trying by myself, using regex, rendering partials by themselves with mixed results... when the solution was that simple!  
Thanks a lot, it's a life saver!