# How to replace a string in template twig?

Tags: php, html, twig

I have a template twig in html for example:

```
<p>Test document</p>

<p>However</p>
```

I would like to replace the word 'Test' in the include template.
`{% include '@template/testing' %}`

Is there some solution to replace the word in the include statement?

I tried to use replace inside the `{% include '@template/testing' %}` but I don`t how to start it.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/replace.html)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Twig: Replace placeholder in string with include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66122633/twig-replace-placeholder-in-string-with-include)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a closer look at the docs:

> Included templates have access to the variables of the active context.
> ...
> You can add additional variables by passing them after the with keyword:
>
> ```
> {# template.html will have access to the variables from the current context and the additional ones provided #}
> {% include 'template.html' with {'foo': 'bar'} %}
>
> {% set vars = {'foo': 'bar'} %}
> {% include 'template.html' with vars %}
> ```
>
> You can disable access to the context by appending the only keyword:
>
> ```
> {# only the foo variable will be accessible #}
> {% include 'template.html' with {'foo': 'bar'} only %}
> {# no variables will be accessible #}
> {% include 'template.html' only %}
> ```
>
> -- https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/include.html

That means you can set a variable in the current template and reference the variable in the included template, where you can also define a default value.

### template/testing:

```
<p>{{ doc_name|default('Test') }} document</p>

<p>However</p>
```

### current template:

```
{% set doc_name = 'new name' %}
{% include '@template/testing' %}
```

Or pass it directly in one line:

```
{% include '@template/testing' with {'doc_name':'new name'} %}
```

Same, but included template will **not** have access to the variables of the active context:

```
{% include '@template/testing' with {'doc_name':'new name'} only %}
```

Any of these methods will render:

```html
<p>new name document</p>

<p>However</p>
```

[Here is a good explanation for all this.](https://craftquest.io/articles/passing-data-with-a-twig-include-statement)

Answer (score -2):

I found a solution

```
{%- set block_modify -%}
{% include 'template.html' %}
{%- endset -%}

{% if 'Hi' in block_modify %}

{{ block_modify | replace ({'Hi':'Hello'}) | raw}}

{% endif %}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).